# Copying values to and from QStringList to QString Array[]

Tags: c++, qt4, qstring

In my C++ GUI program, I am storing a sequence of text ( e.g. option1,option2,option3,option4,option5,option6) in the QString Array[6].

Now, I want to pass this values (i.e. all 6 of them through various functions / signals / slots) as and when required and operate on them individually.

But since QString array[] can not be passed in such a way between functions, I am planning to use QStringList.

Now, I have loaded my array[6] with the values and I am doing the following to copy them;

```
QStringList mylist;

for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
    mylist << array[i];
}
QString item;
foreach(item, mylist);
qDebug()<<"The QSTRINGLIST IS "<<item;

qDebug()<<"The order of options (L-R) " << array[0] << array[1] << array[2] << array[3] << array[4] << array[5];
```

So ideally both the qDebugs should give same response right ??? but in my case the qDebug of QStrinList is returning only the last value (e.g. option6).

Where am I doing wrong ???

In my consequent planning I am planning to perform the reverse i.e. QStringList to QStrin array[] as well, any insights would be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try getting rid of the semicolon after your loop.

`foreach(item, mylist)`

Comment: oh my god, now that is a real noobish silly mistake. thanks a ton.